# Custom Paypay payment protection

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm doing a PayPal payment system. The steps are:

1. collect all item & price value that user have chose, through js get from html input.
2. redirect to url paypal and add on item and price:

   `https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_cart&upload=1&business=someemail@here.com&cy_code=USD&lc=US&item_name_1=Black
   Gold&item_number_1=1&quantity_1=1&amount_1=$58.00`

Question: 
But using this method, user can change the price easily by downloading the page from my site and changing the script. So any protection I can do for this?

I have 2 ideas now. But I don't think they're good solutions.

1. encode/decode the price by server site
2. get the price value from sql ...

Comment: Why are you using script to pass the values in an ASP.NET form, why not just grab them on the post-back in the code behind?

Comment: If a user chooses to pay an incorrect amount, that's up to them isn't it? You'd need to independently validate the payment amount some other way before proceeding with any further action anyway wouldn't you?

Answer (score 1):

Use a POST request to send the data and not a GET request (using URL params). Also, use the PayPal IPN notification system to notify you in the situation that somebody tampers with passed values using a hack:

https://www.paypal.com/ipn